# Slider height - image exceeds slider section

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the height of a slider, but the frame for the slider itself is the only thing that changes, the image remains the same size. Picture of result: [image: result]

It's like I'm not targeting the right CSS element, but when I inspect with firebug, there is nothing else to edit. I've tried setting the height as `300px` (as an example) for the following classes:
`.featured-slider`, `.slider-cycle`, `.slides`, `.displayblock`, `.container`, and `.featured-image`. I've also tried styling the background, the area of the image still remains the same.

Comment: _"I hope I've provided enough information."_ Nope. Need a code example.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots instead of code.

Comment: The site looks fine for me on Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Set patent div height to what you want and then add min-height:100% class to image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like the js that runs the slider is setting the `.slider-cycle` class to have a height of 830px each time the slides rotate.

Try changing the fit: 1, line in the ambition-slider-setting.js to fit: 0;